# VSCode intellisense is unusably slow

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed vscode a few days ago, and everything was going great until today. It updated to the newest version today, and now intellisense takes an unusably long amount of time to show autocomplete suggestions. I tried uninstalling **all** of vscode and reinstalling it, but this did not solve the problem. I have a small number of running extensions (basically, an Emacs keymap, Python, GitLens, and the default extensions like TypeScript that are used by VS Code).

What could be going wrong?

### vscode information

Version: 1.41.0
Commit: 9579eda04fdb3a9bba2750f15193e5fafe16b959
Date: 2019-12-11T17:58:38.338Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 18.7.0

### Extension information

Name: Emacs Friendly Keymap
Id: lfs.vscode-emacs-friendly
Version: 0.9.0

Name: GitLens — Git supercharged
Id: eamodio.gitlens
Version: 10.2.0

Name: Python
Id: ms-python.python
Version: 2019.11.50794

Comment: Intellisense for what language?

Comment: Whoops. Intellisense for Python